# Column name not found even it exists in a matrix

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to subset my data based on a condition but I'm getting the following error

```
m <- matrix(995:1005, ncol = 1) # create matrix
colnames(m) <- c("Total") # Assign col name

colnames(m)
a <- subset(m,Total>1000)

> colnames(m)
[1] "Total"
> a <- subset(m,Total>1000)
Error in subset.matrix(m, Total>1000) : object 'Total' not found
```

Am I overlooking something here? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why are the down votes here?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subset` like:

```
m[subset(m, select = "Total") > 1000, ]
```